# How to change the cursor during a drag and drop action in MudBlazor?

Tags: css, .net, blazor, mudblazor

How can I change the cursor when I grab an item and drag it to a different area where it is possible to drop the item? By default, the cursor is set to 'copy', and I would like to change the cursor to 'move'.